# smali inject code referencing to android.R.id.content

Tags: java, android, smali, apktool

I have decoded an apk (project A) and want to inject smali code from project B 
. The code is a one liner, referencing to the root id of the current activity layout. The one liner java code from project B looks like:

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Compiled and decompiled back to smali its:

```
const v1, 0x1020002
invoke-virtual {p0, v1}, Lbiz/mardal/dangler/MainActivity;->findViewById(I)Landroid/view/View;
move-result-object v0
check-cast v0, Landroid/view/ViewGroup;
```

So I injected this smali snippet into my smali project A and build successfully, but execution crashes. I suspect that `const v1, 0x1020002` does not reference to `android.R.id.content`, but to something else. So v1 does contain another value and most like different type, which gets passed into the findViewById() method. Which crashes.

Any idea how to get the root layout id using smali. Any workaround appreciated!

Comment: Try asking that question [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: good hint, here the question on reverse-engineering stack: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15588/android-smali-inject-code-referencing-to-android-r-id-content